# Puppet on Debian 6 (Squeeze) obsolete

Tags: linux, debian, puppet

I am trying to use puppet on a Debian Squeeze VM. The modules are not recognized, and errors in the init.pp are found. For example, for the apache module :

> ==> default: Syntax error at ')' at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-1c590e71e741d5be
>   cdd0f5f0cf8d12ab/apache/manifests/init.pp:75 on node squeeze64.vagrantup.com

This module is from the puppet forge, and works perfectly on Debian 7, so I do not think it is the cause of the problem.

My hypothesis is that the problem comes from Puppet version, which is 2.6.2 (and is officialy obsolete). I tried updating it with `apt-get` and also following the procedure described on [Puppetlabs](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/install_puppet/install_debian_ubuntu.html?_ga=1.222242328.1804352980.1432287769), that is to say :

```
wget https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-squeeze.deb
sudo dpkg -i puppetlabs-release-squeeze.deb
sudo apt-get update
```

But the version remains the same. So this not working, does that mean puppet does not work on Debian Squeeze at all ? Or is my guess wrong and the problem comes from elsewhere ?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: After installing the puppetlabs repo, you will want to check what's going to happen to your packages using `apt-cache policy puppet`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @FelixFrank, I'm gonna try that.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your /etc/apt/sources.list:

deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main

then enter the commands:

apt-get update

apt-get -t squeeze-backports install puppet

this will install puppet 2.7 for you